# How to use distributed data parallelism in PyTorch with large datasets with expensive chunk read times?

Tags: database, machine-learning, pytorch, sparse-matrix

I have a dataset consisting of 100 .npz files containing a 98% sparse scipy CSR matrices of shape (285341, 60664) where rows are number of samples and columns are feature size. I want to run a Variational Autoencoder over the dataset. I have access to Large Memory Nodes (1.5TB RAM each), Compute nodes (190GB RAM total) and 4 GPU's (190GB RAM total). At the moment the main bottle neck is loading the data as the entire dataset cannot fit into memory at once. What are some suggestions that still allow random shuffling and cut down on read times?

What has been tried:

- Used MapDataset that spins off loading thread that continually populates queue and randomly shuffles on load. Seems to work on just one GPU but no way of distributing among workers.
- IterableDataset that does the same as MapDataset but uses worker_init_fn splits what load but keep getting unimplemented error. (Note: Class is too big and scary but can be attached if needed as well as the DataLoader init call)